Stop NSolve after a certain amount of time and return calculated solutions
I am trying to solve a system of equations of the form:
NSolve[{fs1[{x, y, z}] - 2*l*x == 0,   fs2[{x, y, z}] - 2*l*y == 0,   fs3[{x, y, z}] - 2*l*z == 0, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1}, {x, y,   z, l}, Reals]
where $f_{s1}$, $f_{s2}$ and $f_{s3}$ are polynomials of order $N=192$ in $x,y$ and $z$. Obviously there are a lot of solutions and Mathematica will take a long time to find all of them. However, I'm not interested in finding every solution, just 'enough'.
Is there any way I can terminate NSolve after say $7200$ seconds ($2$ hours) and get Mathematica to return the solutions that it found up to that point? I previously attempted to use TimeConstrained[NSolve[...],7200] but that just returns $Aborted.
Below is an example of fs1 etc.:
fs1[\[Xi]_] := 
 1/n*Sum[Sum[GegenbauerC[\[Nu] - 1, 1.5, 
      Dot[\[Xi], {terX[[i]], terY[[i]], 
        terZ[[i]]}]]*terX[[i]], {\[Nu], 1, Subscript[N, 
     s]}], {i, 1, n}]

fs2[\[Xi]_] := 
 1/n*Sum[Sum[GegenbauerC[\[Nu] - 1, 1.5, 
      Dot[\[Xi], {terX[[i]], terY[[i]], 
        terZ[[i]]}]]*terY[[i]], {\[Nu], 1, Subscript[N, 
     s]}], {i, 1, n}]


fs3[\[Xi]_] := 
 1/n*Sum[Sum[GegenbauerC[\[Nu] - 1, 1.5, 
      Dot[\[Xi], {terX[[i]], terY[[i]], 
        terZ[[i]]}]]*terZ[[i]], {\[Nu], 1, Subscript[N, 
     s]}], {i, 1, n}]

where $N_s=192, n=4500$ and terX, terY and  terZ are just vectors containing $n$ coefficients.

What happens if you ask FindInstance to give you 4 or 40 solutions?

@Bill, FindInstance, seems to find an analytical solution. I can't find anything in the documentation about making it find a numerical solution instead.

Without seeing example fs1,fs2,fs3 it is difficult to guess what to say. Can you provide some much smaller fs1,fs2,fs3, just big enough to demonstrate your problem, but not so huge that it takes a long time? Something that demonstrates the kind of solution you are getting now and give an example of the solution you would like. It might be a simple fix, can't know without more info.

@Bill, I've just edited the question to include the form of the functions

updated in 14.0: NSolve has  a MaxRoots option to specify the number of roots you want to find
